# Detect voltage below 0.7V?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, low-voltage, trigger

I have a LED in circuit which I want a circuit to detect whether it's on or not.

I have found ground and +ve of the circuit.

And I checked the voltage across +ve of LED and Ground, when it is ON, it came 0.36V

Now trouble is transistor need 0.7V to trigger, and Op-Amp Comparator(LM358) doesn't seems to work for this, also not sure why I can't detect this voltage on ADC of Arduino.

Please tell me if there is a way to clamp this voltage so that it trigger a transistor, or if there is other way to detect that LED.

Please help me on this !

Comment: Is it just me...........? Lost!

Comment: Please add a schematic to show how your LED is being driven. It's unlikely to be lighting up with only 0.36V across it so you have something wrong.

Comment: Visible LEDs need more than 1.5V to turn on, so there is something wrong with your measurement or interpretation. Measure carefully and use the Circuitlab function to post a proper partial schematic.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to hack into washing machine and find out which mode is selected by user by looking at with LED is ON.
So I don't really understand how the LED in driven, and most of the circuit is masked with thick coating which makes it difficult to prob and do continuty tests.
When i check voltage across on LED's positive and Ground, I get 0.36V, which is weird as LED is also semiconductor which should also need 0.7V

Comment: put additional information into your question

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!! danger !!!!!!!!!!!!! ... the control board in a washing machine may have full line voltage on it 120V/220V AC

Comment: I assume "won't" should be "want"

Comment: Are you using the frame of the washer as ground point? or are you going directly across the leads of the LED?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Please edit your question to add detail, don't put it in comments. Otherwise you're expecting people to piece it all together in their head. Thanks.

Comment: @jsotola Yes I am staying clear off the high voltage.

Comment: @oldfart I am sorry I didn't get the reference.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks, I am not trying to get other design for me, apologies if that message is getting through. I have tried a lot of things, but I should have mentioned it properly in question. I just want to know such kind of scenario how do you detect whether LED is ON or not.
I will put more details in question.

Answer (score 3):

Optically couple a photodiode to each LED you want to monitor.  Interface the photodiodes to your arduino.  You will then no longer be concerned with what voltages exist under the thick mask covering the circuit board, and you and your arduino will be isolated from potentially lethal voltage.

Comment: Yes that's the first thing I tried, but as it did not trigger Optocoupler, and when I checked the voltage across the LED I was getting 0.36V, what could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: The suggestion is to use a photodiode to detect the light emitted by the existing LED.  With this, no electrical connection to the board  is required.  It doesn't matter what voltage is on the board.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong.  An LED does not have a 0.7v forward voltage like that of a signal diode.

Red, orange, amber, and yellow will have a forward voltage of about 2 volts.
White, blue and green will have a forward voltage of about 3 volts.

Without a schematic, no one can help you much, post one.

Comment: Not sure how I can take out schematic out of that PCB, that too without continuity test available :(

Answer (score 0):

If the LED does not emit a wavelength visible to the human eye. Just like the infrared LED used in remote controls. You can use a cell phone camera to make sure it's on.

Remember that when measuring the electronic component connected to a circuit, consideration should be given to the voltage drop on the components in parallel.

It is important to check:

=> the nominal input voltage of the circuit is correct.
=> if the pin of the integrated component output (search in data sheet) of the component is able to power the LED. Meanwhile I recommend using a separate trigger circuit if you are developing.
=> look for other power losses in the circuit.

Comment: So that means due to parallel circuitry to LED I might be getting wrong voltage ?